# Laravel fromSubquery() Syntax translation. Postgres Statement

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

Since laravel 6 there is the ability to add From Subquery statements.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/29602

The examples given for the syntax are this:

```php
$query->select('name')
    ->from(function ($query) {
        $query->something();
    }, 'users')
    ->get();

DB::table(function ($query) {
    $query->something();
}, 'users')->get();
```

I'm very confused what's the difference between the two and how to implement it. Given I have the following postgresSQL query to find the streaks (consecutive dates) where a user does a session.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) streak, SUM(amount) streakAmount, MIN(date) startDate, MAX(date) endDate, dateMinusRow dateMinusRow
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) amount, date_trunc('day', start) date,
           date_trunc('day', start) - INTERVAL '1' DAY * DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('day', start)) dateMinusRow
    FROM sessions
    WHERE user_id = ".$this->user->id."
    GROUP BY date_trunc('day', start)
) groupedDays
GROUP BY dateMinusRow
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to add the surrounding query, I think I got the from() part down:

```php
DB::table(function ($query) {
    $query->selectRaw("
        COUNT(*) amount,
        date_trunc('day', start) date,
        date_trunc('day', start) - INTERVAL '1' DAY * DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('day', start)) dateMinusRow"
            )
        ->from('sessions')
        ->where('user_id', $this->user->id)
        ->groupByRaw("date_trunc('day', start)");
}, 'groupedDays')
```

But I don't understand how I should put the top-level select and groupBy clauses

Answer (score 1):

You're not forced to use that syntax.

- `from()` is used to specify a table **when you're using a subquery.**
- `table()` is used to specify the main table you're querying.

You can pass an optional alias as a second parameter in both of those methods.

Examples:

```
DB::table('users', 'u')->select('id as ID')->get();
// select id as ID from users as u
DB::table(function($sq) {
    $sq->select('id')->from('users'); // must specify from when using subquery
})->select('id')->get();
// select id from (select id from users)
DB::table(function($sq) {
    $sq->select('id'); // not specifying from leads to a bad query
})->select('id')->get();
// select id from (select id)
```

If you'd rather separate the queries from each other, you can do that as well

```
$subquery = DB::table('users')->select('id'); // $subquery will be a Query Builder instance you can pass to table() or from() instead of a Closure.
$query    = DB::table($subquery, 'alias')->select('id');
$results  = $query->get();
// select id from (select id from users) as alias
```

My advice: Use the `toSql()` method to ensure your queries are correct. Start by just making the subquery.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) streak,
  SUM(amount) streakAmount,
  MIN(date) startDate,
  MAX(date) endDate,
  dateMinusRow
FROM
# Start Subquery
(
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) amount,
    date_trunc('day', start) date,
    date_trunc('day', start) - INTERVAL '1' DAY * DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('day', start)) dateMinusRow
  FROM sessions
  WHERE user_id = ".$this->user->id."
  GROUP BY date_trunc('day', start)
) groupedDays
# End Subquery
GROUP BY dateMinusRow
```

```
$subquery = DB::table('sessions')
  ->selectRaw(
    "COUNT(*) as amount, "
    ."date_trunc('day', start) as date, "
    ."date_trunc('day', start) - INTERVAL '1' DAY * DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('day', start)) as dateMinusRow "
  )
  ->where('user_id', $this->user->id)
  ->groupByRaw("date_trunc('day', start)");
// Verify the subquery is correct by dumping $subquery->toSql();
$query = DB::table($subquery, 'groupedDays')
  ->selectRaw(
    "COUNT(*) as streak, "
    ."SUM(amount) as streakAmount, "
    ."MIN(date) as startDate, "
    ."MAX(date) as endDate, "
    ."dateMinusRow "
  )
  ->groupBy('dateMinusRow');
// Verify the query is correct by dumping $query->toSql();
$results = $query->get();
```

I'm not an expert with postgres so I'm assuming the original query works.

#### Edit

The `from()` is not present in my original answer because I'm not using a Closure subquery but passing in a Query Builder instance. This is how it would look if I used `from()`. In my opinion, it's messier to work with.

```
$query2 = DB::table(function($subquery) {
  $subquery->from('sessions')
    ->selectRaw(
      "COUNT(*) as amount, "
      ."date_trunc('day', start) as date, "
      ."date_trunc('day', start) - INTERVAL '1' DAY * DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('day', start)) as dateMinusRow "
    )
    ->where('user_id', $this->user->id)
    ->groupByRaw("date_trunc('day', start)");
}, 'groupedDays')
  ->selectRaw(
    "COUNT(*) as streak, "
    ."SUM(amount) as streakAmount, "
    ."MIN(date) as startDate, "
    ."MAX(date) as endDate, "
    ."dateMinusRow "
  )
  ->groupBy('dateMinusRow');
// Verify the query is correct by dumping $query2->toSql();
$results = $query->get();
```

Dumping both queries, the only difference I seem to get in the Sql is the use of backticks.

```
>>> $query->toSql()
=> "select COUNT(*) as streak, SUM(amount) as streakAmount, MIN(date) as startDate, MAX(date) as endDate, dateMinusRow  from (select COUNT(*) as amount, date_trunc('day', start) as d
ate, date_trunc('day', start) - INTERVAL '1' DAY * DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('day', start)) as dateMinusRow  from "sessions" where "user_id" = ? group by date_trunc('day
', start)) as "groupedDays" group by "dateMinusRow""
>>> $query2->toSql()
=> "select COUNT(*) as streak, SUM(amount) as streakAmount, MIN(date) as startDate, MAX(date) as endDate, dateMinusRow  from (select COUNT(*) as amount, date_trunc('day', start) as d
ate, date_trunc('day', start) - INTERVAL '1' DAY * DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('day', start)) as dateMinusRow  from `sessions` where `user_id` = ? group by date_trunc('day
', start)) as `groupedDays` group by `dateMinusRow`"
```

The issue with the query might be tied to one of the database driver's options. I don't know for sure, but to give an example some `group by` queries do not work on Laravel, even if the generated sql code is correct **unless** strict mode is disabled in the mysql driver.

As for why I use the `as` keyword, the databases I work with are usually either mysql or postgresql so I tend to use the notation they both share.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and your answer. Concatenation is not necessary inside selectRaw statements. The original query is correct since I already use this inside my laravel app, but I use it as DB::select(" // full statement here"). Which is very nasty. Also your code doesn't recognize the subquery. When I call "dateMinusRow" it errors on column not found, so the custom named calculated value from the first subquery does not seem to work. Also the 'as' keyword can be removed in postgres. Also 'from()) is completely missing from your answer?

Comment: I've added a bit of an explanation

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I upvoted the answer for your effort and the subquery differences are more clear for me now, so thank you! But I can't accept the answer because the answer gives an error, Tried with different formats, but can't get the groupBy() working.